# Webpack not creating bundle.js or error messages

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, webpack, babeljs

I've tried installing webpack and babel-loader into my vue project. When I run 'npm run dev' in my terminal, I don't get any bundled files outputted to my dist folder and I get the following message:

`> vueproject@0.1.0 dev`

`> webpack --watch --progress --mode=development`

If I run `npm run serve`, I get this:

```html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import requests
| from django.shortcuts import render
| from rest_framework import viewsets
| from django.db import connection  # This is for the my_custom_sql method.

 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js 5:0-52 139:18-31
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://172.25.10.80:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

If I run `npm run build`, I get this error:

```html
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHubRepositories\Django_Repository\DB_Vue_Project\vueproject\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\CssDependency.js:12:46)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHubRepositories\Django_Repository\DB_Vue_Project\vueproject\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\index.js:12:45)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vueproject@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vueproject@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-28T03_13_56_408Z-debug.log
```

Here's my file structure in my project:

```html
-vueproject
 -dist
 -src
  -deletethis.js
 package.json
 package-lock.json
 webpack.config.js
 babel.config.js
```

package.json:

```html
{
  "name": "vueproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack --watch --progress --mode=development",
    "prod": "webpack --mode=production",
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.1.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss": "^8.2.9",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```html
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path'); // Define the path module, which is used for handling and transforming file paths.
module.exports = { // Makes the object on the right side of the equals sign available to the outside world (webpack).
    context: __dirname, // Allows 'entry' to take the root of the path that you have defined.
    entry: 'src/deletethis.js', // Tells webpack which file(s)/modules it needs to bundle.
    output: { // Defines where webpack outputs the bundled file.
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'testdeletethis.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [ // Ensures that whenever webpack finds a *.js file, it uses babel-loader to convert it to ES5.
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I've looked around the internet for a few hours today but wasn't able to find anything quite like what I'm running into. I find it odd that those two lines are all that I'm getting when I run 'npm run dev'. Any help with this issue would be appreciated. Thanks, all!

Comment: Update: I have tried running `npm run dev` and `npm run prod` but, neither of these create the bundle.js file I'm looking for and don't fix the `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` error I get when running `npm run serve`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dev` script only runs the Webpack dev server, so nothing would be written into `dist`. Also, bundling only occurs (and the `dist` folder created and filled) when you run the `build` script (`npm run build`).

But your project appears to be a Vue CLI scaffolded project (based on the `@vue/cli-service` dependencies), which transitively depends on Webpack, so you don't need to add a dependency on `webpack` or `webpack-cli`.

Your Webpack config doesn't seem to do anything that isn't already done by default in Vue CLI scaffolded projects. I recommend just sticking with the `serve` and `build` scripts. If you need to change the Webpack config, use `vue.config.js`'s [`configureWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack) or [`chainWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack). See [*Working with Webpack*](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#working-with-webpack) for reference.

Comment: When running `npm run serve`, I get `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import requests
| from django.shortcuts import render
| from rest_framework import viewsets
| from django.db import connection  # This is for the my_custom_sql method....`. Thanks for the help on this problem!

Comment: When running `npm run build`, I get `TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null...`.

Comment: How did you create this project? With Vue CLI? Or by hand? Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: Here is a link to the repository on GitHub: https://github.com/Stochastis/TestRepository.git. This is my team's and my first project that we're doing for our Database class so, it's definitely messy but, we would absolutely appreciate any critiques or help!